# My test case is not detecting account team member?

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
trigger AccountTeam on Account (after insert) {
    Integer newcnt = 0;
    Integer newcnt0 = 0;
    AccountTeamMember[] newmembers = new AccountTeamMember[]{};
    //list of new team members to add
    AccountShare[] newShare = new AccountShare[]{};
    //list of new shares to add

    Id recTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where SObjectType ='Account' And Name = 'Prospect/Customer' Limit 1][0].Id;

    //get the user id of the user running the trigger, anyone that changes the Account will added to the account team
    for(Account a:trigger.new) {
  if(( a.billingcountry=='united kingdom')&&(a.ownerid=='00590000000fmwp')&&(a.recordtypeid==recTypeId)){
        AccountTeamMember Teammemberad=new AccountTeamMember();
        Teammemberad.AccountId=a.id;
        Teammemberad.UserId='00590000000fq2z';
        Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'sales Assistant';
        newmembers.add(Teammemberad);
    }
}
    Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(newmembers,false);
    //insert any valid members then add their share entry if they were successfully added Integer newcnt=0;
    for(Database.SaveResult sr:lsr) {
        if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
            Database.Error emsg =sr.getErrors()[0];

            system.debug('\n\nERROR ADDING TEAM MEMBER:'+emsg);
        } else {

     newShare.add(new AccountShare(UserOrGroupId=newmembers[newcnt].UserId, AccountId=newmembers[newcnt].Accountid, AccountAccessLevel='Edit',OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit'));
        }
        newcnt++;
    }

}
```

i have a test case as like this :

```
@istest
public class testaccountteam{
static testmethod void unittest(){
Account a= new account(name='test',billingcountry='india');
insert a;
account u1=[select id,ownerid from account where id=:a.id];
id uid=u1.ownerid;
//AccountTeamMember[] newmembers = new AccountTeamMember[]{};
//integer  i;
accountteammember atm= new accountteammember();
atm.AccountId=a.id;
atm.userid=u1.ownerid;
atm.teammemberrole='Sales Assistant';
insert atm;
update a;
system.assertequals(atm.accountid,a.id);
//newmembers.add(atm);
}
}
```

This portion is not detecting in the code coverage can any body guide me:

> ```
>   AccountTeamMember Teammemberad = new AccountTeamMember();
>   Teammemberad.AccountId = a.id;
>   Teammemberad.UserId = '00590000000fq2z';
>   Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'sales Assistant';
>   newmembers.add(Teammemberad);
> ```

i wrote another test case:

```
@isTest
private class testAccountteam {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        string tcaseid;
        User standinguser = [select id,name from user where name = 'Alexis de lassat' LIMIT 1];

        Test.StartTest();

        account testcase = new account(name='test', billingcountry='india');  //add other required fields as necessary

        try{
            insert testcase;
            tcaseid=testcase.id;
        }catch(DMLException d){
            system.assert(false, '\n\nERROR OCCURRED INSERTING TEST CASE: '+d.getDMLMessage(0));
        }

        Test.StopTest();

        //Start validation
        Account[] checkcase = [select id,name from account where id=:tcaseid];
        system.assert(checkcase.size()>0);    
        accountTeamMember[] findMember = [select id,accountid,UserId,TeamMemberRole from accountTeamMember where accountid=:tcaseid and UserId=:standinguser.id];
        system.assert(findMember.size()>0,'\n\nCaseMember was not added correctly');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues.  First I would highly recommend the hardcoding of IDs that you are using in your code.  Not the best practice (see #10 below).  Look here for some best practices

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

For your code, you have logic looking only for accounts with `BillingCountry = 'United Kingdom'`.  In your test code, you are setting the Billing Country to India.  So the code will not make it inside of your If statement, thus the code coverage reflecting that.

You need to set up your test data to match what yu are checking for in your trigger.  Your trigger is looking for 3 things

Billing Country = 'United Kingdom'

OwnerId = Some hardcoded ID

RecordType = Prospect/Customer

```
 Id recTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where SObjectType ='Account' And Name = 'Prospect/Customer' Limit 1][0].Id;

 Profile myProf = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];//or whatever profile you want
 User u = new User(LastName = 'Test', email = 'test@domain.com', Alias = 'myAlias', EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', UserName = username, profileId = myProf.Id);
 insert u;

 //This asserts that prior to adding the account, there are no accountteammembers
 list<AccountTeamMember> atms = [Select Id, Name From AccountTeamMember];
 system.assertEquals(0, atms.size());

 Account a = new account(name='test', BillingCountry = 'United Kingdom', OwnerId = u.Id, RecordTypeId = recTypeId);
 insert a;

 //Shows that after your trigger fires, there is now a team member in the system
 atms = [Select Id, Name From AccountTeamMember];
 system.assertEquals(1, atms.size());

 //Asserts that the team member that was added was your test user, on your test account, and the role that is specified in your trigger
 AccountTeamMember atm = [Select UserId, AccountId, TeamMemberRole From AccountTeamMember Where AccountId = a.Id And userId = u.Id];

 system.assertEquals(atm.TeamMemberRole, 'Sales Assistant');
```

Notice that I put in some assertion statements.  Although getting 75% code coverage will allow you to deploy to production, you really should assertion statements to your test code. Without assertions, you really aren't actually testing anything, you're just testing that your code doesn't crash, and not that it produces the expected result.  Here are a few links to some testing information

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

Comment: very thankful . ya i know i am very weak at test cases i am improving bit by bit thankyou a lot